# sed: match two lines

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a text file, where records are split on two lines. I would like to put them on one line. The records look something like this:

```
2013-07-29
 apt-get install git
2013-07-29
 apt-get install rsync
2013-07-31
 apt-get install nmap
2013-08-02
 apt-get install cifs-utils
2013-08-05
 apt-get install telnet
```

I would like to get the following:

```
2013-07-29 apt-get install git
2013-07-29 apt-get install rsync
2013-07-31 apt-get install nmap
2013-08-02 apt-get install cifs-utils
2013-08-05 apt-get install telnet
```

I tried with `sed`, but I am unable to match two lines. Is there some trick in `sed`, or is there some better tool ?

Comment: It seems less like you want to match two lines, and more you want to join the line after you find a match.  Yes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

- `N` joins next input line to the pattern space
- `s/\n/ /` replaces the new-line that separates the lines with a space.

or:

```
sed -n 'N;s/\n/ /;/regex/p'
```

- `-n` disables automatic printing of pattern space as last command
- `/regex/p` prints lines matching regex

Use the `g` modifier for the substitutions in case you are joining more than two lines, e.g. `N;N;N;s/\n/ /g`.

Comment: *point to remember: sed works on lines!* 
i spent ages trying to get `sed 's/>\n</>,</'` to work until i realised that sed works on lines at a time.  one quick duckduckgo search and @peterph allowed me to keep the rest of my hair

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the `apt-get` lines have a preceding whitespace.  Saying:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n / /;ta' -e 'P;D' inputfile
```

should produce the desired result.

Alternatively, you can also use `paste`:

```
paste -d' ' - - < inputfile
```